# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key "Projects"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, razor

I'm new with MVC Razor. I'm trying to insert to de DB but I get this expection:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key "Projects"

I'm using EntityFramework (DB First) as my MVC model. I get this error in my DropDownList, I retrieve data with Linq to populate my DropDwonList, this is my code:

**Controller:**

```
// GET: /Actividad/

public ActionResult AgregarActividad()
{
    var db = new WTMEntities();

    var proyectos = (from pro in db.Proyecto
                     select new
                     {
                         Id = pro.Id,
                         Nombre = pro.Nombre
                     }).ToList();
    ViewData["Projects"] = new SelectList(proyectos.Select(i => i.Nombre));

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AgregarActividad(Actividades act)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var db = new WTMEntities();

        var proyectos = (from pro in db.Proyecto
                         select new
                         {
                             Id = pro.Id,
                             Nombre = pro.Nombre
                         }).ToList();
        ViewData["Projects"] = new SelectList(proyectos.Select(i => i.Nombre));

        var actividad = db.Set<Actividades>();
        actividad.Add(act);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div>
    <p>Proyecto</p>
    @Html.DropDownList(
    "Projects", null, string.Empty, new { style = "width: 200px;" })
</div>
```

If someone could give me a hand, I will really appreciate!!

Comment: In your POST method you have an `else` statement that returns the view, but you do not repopulate `ViewData["Projects"]` so its null resulting in the exception

Comment: Thank you!! @StephenMuecke that actually was the problem. Greetings

Comment: And you can simplify those 7 lines to `ViewData["Projects"] = new SelectList(db.Proyecto, "Nombre", "Nombre");` and then put it in a private method since you call it multiple times.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I prefer to use the PRG pattern for invalid postbacks. Granted it requires some additional work when it comes to viewstate, as it's not persisted between requests. but that can be solved by migrating the needed information into TempData, and then back again on the subsequent action. Attributes do a great job of this.

Comment: I'll check this of PRG pattern @NickAlbrecht thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post method isn't repopulating the ViewData.
I've modified your code... find below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AgregarActividad(Actividades act)
{
var db = new WTMEntities();

        var proyectos = (from pro in db.Proyecto
                         select new
                         {
                             Id = pro.Id,
                             Nombre = pro.Nombre
                         }).ToList();
        ViewData["Projects"] = new SelectList(proyectos.Select(i => i.Nombre));

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var actividad = db.Set<Actividades>();
        actividad.Add(act);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! that was the problem ;)